# Search Up DOM from a given element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jquery, I'm trying to find a way to search up the dom until it finds the selector.  For example.

Provided this structure:

```
<span data-type="contact" data-filter="4" id="buyer-lookup" class="uneditable-input contact-lookup" data-original-title="" title="">Jeff</span>
<div class="popover">
   <div class="arrow"></div>
   <h3 class="popover-title"><strong>Jeff</strong></h3>
   <div class="popover-content">
      <address style="margin:0;"> MO<br></address>
      <a data-id="70" data-type="contact" class="pull-right edit-contact" href="#">Edit</a>
      <div class="clear"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

On click of '.edit-contact' I'd like to search up until I find 'span.contact-lookup'.  I can use parent a couple of times to get what I want like below, but is there a cleaner way so that you can just specify $(this).searchUpFunction('span.contact-lookup'); so it would start at this and search up until it finds span.contact-lookup?  .prev doesn't seem to search up parents.

```
$('.edit-contact').click(function(){
       var filter = $(this).parent().parent().prev('span.contact-lookup').data('filter');
       alert(filter);
    });
```

Comment: A quicker way, given your DOM fragment would be `$(this).closest('div.popover').prev()`

Comment: In order to search up, you have the [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function, but in your case, since you are looking for the previous node of an ancestor, there is no direct function for that in jQuery... Nevertheless, you can try : `$(this).closest(".popover").prev()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$('.edit-contact').click(function(){
   contactID = $(this).closest('div.popover').prev().data('contact-id');
   alert(contactID);
});
```

Comment: There is no such function `.previous()`.

Comment: the span isn't part of the ancestors, it preceds the div ancestor

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any information about the ancestor where `span.contact-lookup` is the sibling of, you can use [`.parents()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/parents/) to select all ancestors:

```
$(this).parents().prev('span.contact-lookup')
```

This will be less efficient than using `.closest()` though, since it will traverse the tree up to the root.

Additionally, if there are multiple ancestors with a `span.contact-lookup` sibling, you will select all of those. In this case you can get the nearest one with `.first()` or `.last()`, depending on the order they are selected in (the order will always be the same, I just don't know it off the top of my head).

---

So: If you can, use `.closest`, if not, `.parents` is probably your best bet (apart from writing your own code to traverse the DOM).